# My .htaccess has broken my laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I recently migrated my website from Dream ocean to hostgator but some of the links and signup form stopped working at http://www.smartynight.com/
The only link that works is http://www.smartynight.com/about
Other links return a 404 response and the login system does not send form data.

My .htaccess code:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

when i delete the codes in the .htaccess file, the about link that was working before just stops.
pasting the codes back fixes the about page

All pages are located at resources/views/pages/
And the routes points to that folder

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`  I don't think you need this `/` in `/$1` in front of the `$1` - not sure if that is the problem but consider this `/somelocation/` ~ `//somelocation`  also the last rule I genarally see as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` but I don't use Laravel so not sure if that is what they suggest using etc.  Which is used to retain the URI part of the URL.  `/index.php/somelocation` instead of just `index.php`

Comment: I just removed the / in /$1 but it still doesn't work. New update is the terms and services page now works

Comment: Drop `RewriteBase /` or replace it with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`